# How can i fuzzy match between two columns in my pandas data frame?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I tried to perform fuzzy match between two columns in my pandas data frame but could not get the right result. Could someone please help me with this one.

[What I have tried so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCZGS.png)

Comment: Hey. I can't open the image for some reason. can you probably type stuff and describe a bit.

Comment: Col1 = ['Rajan','Sujan','Dame']
Col2 = ['Rohan','Sanjan','Darmian']

I want to fuzzy match these columns and get match score.

I tried to create a new column as below:

df['Match Score'] = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(df['Col1'],['Col2'])

But I am only getting one value back in my Match Score column and it is not correct.